# How do I use Ajax with jQuery in Perl?

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl

If I call this function directly it works fine, yet if I call it from Javascript using an ajax call it wont work correctly.

I found out the reason for this, it was cause I was using $(document).ready(function ..) where I should call the functions directly after the ajax returns the results.

Comment: Work on learning the markdown formatting so that this question can make more sense by formatting the code.

Comment: This is a part of the code you are seeing. Actually the javascript is being called when the user clicks on something. I don't want it to work directly when loading.

Comment: also: `escape` shouldn't be used, its output is similar to (but incompatible with) URL-encoding. `encodeURI` isn't quite right either. Replace both with `encodeURIComponent`. However if you are using jQuery as the tags say, you can just pass in `{target: 'get_section'}` to the `ajax` (or `post`) method and it'll work out the encoding for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So confusing, your perl code just outputs html without any headers (like content-type). Your javascript doesn't seem to use jQuery, and none of the referred IDs appear anywhere in your example.

Were you looking to use [load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback) something like: `$('#view_span').load('filename_ajax.cgi');`?
Or perhaps:

```
$('#view_span').load(
  'filename_ajax.cgi',
  {'target': escape(encodeURI('get_section'))},
  alertViewResult);
```

Answer (score 4):

At minimum, your Perl script needs to output the following kind of text before any other output:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

Note that there must be an empty line after the `Content-Type` line.

If you fail to do this, the server will not send the text to the JavaScript. Typically it would trip the line

```
alert('There was a problem with the request.');
```

in your JavaScript. If you examine the value of the variable `.status`, it should be equal to 500, an error code which indicates your script failed.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's a bit under-documented (at least for someone who isn't already intimately familiar with jQuery itself), have you taken a look at [JQuery](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JQuery) on CPAN?